# How to create and deploy a Web Application

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I have two working servers (at different locations) with IIS hosting WCF. On each server, WCF (by way of an entity framework) connects to a PostgreSQL database on the same server. My development machine is my laptop.

I have added new stored procedures to the PostgreSQL databases and added these to the WCF implementation on my laptop.

Currently, the Server only has the production site set to use ASP.Net v4.0 application pool.

In Visual Studio 2010 (.Net 4.0), can someone please tell me how to:

1. Create a Web Deployment Application that will use the existing PostgreSQL database already on the Server (I do not want to export any database from my laptop).
2. Create a Web Deployment Application that will use the existing PostgreSQL database already on the Server, but target a non-production site like "TestingSite".
3. Is there anyway of creating a Web Deployment Application that will CREATE the new site, "TestingSite" on the Server with the correct settings.

Ultimately I'm hoping for something really simple that I can develop the WCF code I need on my laptop, then deploy it to the server for testing.

Comment: Did you search the web a little bit? ;-) Take this tutorial as a starting point: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-to-iis

Comment: @khlr yes...for several hours. Everything I found though was importing a new database, which I don't need. Quick glance shows your link maybe what I need. Thanks.